# How to get Media Id of a message template created via WhatsApp Manager?

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

Using WhatsApp Manager I have created a marketing message template with a media image, when I am trying to send a message using Cloud API I am getting the below error.

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Param template['components'][0]['parameters'][0]['image']['id'] is not a valid whatsapp business account media attachment ID","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"XXXXXX-CCCCCC"}}